# Error javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring MVC and Spring Security and hibernate. i am having problem with save 'Password" can not tell  where mistake is

I get the Following Error When i submit my form

```
nested exception is javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.greensungh.jupiter_SHM.model.UsersInfo] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='size must be between 6 and 25', propertyPath=Password, rootBeanClass=class com.greensungh.jupiter_SHM.model.UsersInfo, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}'}
]] with root cause
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.greensungh.jupiter_SHM.model.UsersInfo] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='size must be between 6 and 25', propertyPath=Password, rootBeanClass=class com.greensungh.jupiter_SHM.model.UsersInfo, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}'}
```

this is my view:

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
<div class="controls">
<form:password path="Password" id="password"
class="form-control span8" />
<div class="has-error">
<form:errors path="Password" class="help-inline" />
</div></div></div>
```

The Model:

```
@NotEmpty
    @Size(min=6, max=25)
    @Column(name="PASSWORD", nullable=false)
    private String Password;
```

my messages.properties

```
NotEmpty.userInfo.Password=Password must be blank
Size.userInfo.Password=Password must be between {6} to {25} characters long
```

any ideas

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. The problem was I set the password max to 30 and at the same time I used bcrypt encoder. Bcrypt hashes the password and store it as a random 60 characters which violates the max size constraints. So if you are using an encryption increase you max so your encrypted password meets the size requirement. I hope this helps.